# Deserializing weirdly formatted JSON to an object in C#

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm trying to teach myself working with *API*s, and chose to try and make something that fetches currency exchange rates from a certain free *API* regarding just that. I've managed to successfully make the *API* call and record the **JSON** data from it, and I'd like to save the data so it's easily accessible from an object.

My issue is this; the **JSON** data reads like

```
{
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "EUR",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "Euro",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "0.87490000",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2020-07-19 08:16:36",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
        "8. Bid Price": "0.87490000",
        "9. Ask Price": "0.87540000"
    }
}
```

Using https://json2csharp.com/ I'm getting a result like this

```
public class RealtimeCurrencyExchangeRate    {
    public string 1.From_CurrencyCode { get; set; } 
    public string 2.From_CurrencyName { get; set; } 
    public string 3.To_CurrencyCode { get; set; } 
    public string 4.To_CurrencyName { get; set; } 
    public string 5.ExchangeRate { get; set; } 
    public string 6.LastRefreshed { get; set; } 
    public string 7.TimeZone { get; set; } 
    public string 8.BidPrice { get; set; } 
    public string 9.AskPrice { get; set; } 
}
```

Which isn't valid c# syntax. The JSON parser I have could deserialize that info (I think) but Visual Studio is throwing a well deserved fit over me trying to name a variable `1.From_CurrencyCode`

Comment: You can also deserealize it as `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) attribute (if you're using Newtonsoft.Json) to decorate each of your model properties.  This allows you to rename the Json property names to valid C# property names.

```
public class RealtimeCurrencyExchangeRate    
{
    [JsonProperty("1. From_Currency Code")]
    public string FromCurrencyCode { get; set; } 
    
    // similarly for the remaining properties
    ...
}

// also apply it to your "root" class
public class Root    
{
    [JsonProperty("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate")]
    public RealtimeCurrencyExchangeRate RealtimeCurrencyExchangeRate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't moved to `System.Text.Json` either, I am sticking with `Newtonsoft.Json`.
At the moment I prefer a *convention based approach* to deserialization, in this case I wouldn't pollute my model with json attributes. Furthermore, this looks like a bad api to consume in the first place (imho), those property names are awful.

So, in this case, I'd choose a [*tolerant reader*](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TolerantReader.html) (like Martin Fowler advertises) over strongly typed objects, and one of the 3 techniques below(exclusive OR):

- [Custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm)
- [Querying JSON with dynamic](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm)
- [Deserialize an Anonymous Type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)